How to unwrap an array field in Tableau?
I wonder whether how to create a calculated field and unwrap an array column. My main purpose is to be able to filter according this new unwrapped column. For instance, I have an array for each row containing info on store types:
id 1 = [demand, asap],
id 2 = [asap],
id 3 = [demand, asap, delayed],
id 4 = []; 

and I want to receive an unwrapped version:
id 1 = demand 
id 1 = asap
id 2 = asap
id 3 = demand
id 3 = asap
id 3 = delayed
id 4 = Null

Should I do it with custom SQL? If I should, how do I do it?

First realize multi-valued cells go against the whole concept of relational databases, making some kinds of analysis more difficult than needed. The pure relational approach is to factor out lists of values into a related table, associated with a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.
That said, sometimes they are simple convenient, especially if the analytical tasks for those fields are relatively lightweight - such as just display and filtering.
In those cases, Tableau has a function called Split() that is useful for accessing individual elements from a text list in a calculated field. There is also a shortcut by right clicking on a field and choosing Transform.
If you need more precise analytics, the next step is to reshape your data automatically, say with Tableau Prep, to factor out the repeating lists into a related table. Besides the Split() function, the Pivot operation can be helpful for that.
